# BrokenPipeError while using selenium and chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

While executing the following code to try to scrape a website's index page, and attemptying to identify an element containing login text, as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
chromedriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
my_url = 'https://www.pastest.com/'
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.get(my_url)
driver.quit()
p_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('popup-link')
print(p_element.text)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_pastest.py", line 17, in <module>
    p_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('popup-link')
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 555, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 310, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 466, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 489, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I had specifically added the line `driver.implicitly_wait(15)` to take care of any error of timeout, when I first encountered the error. I had also tried `selenium_client.set_page_load_timeout(10)`, but that didn't help either.

What's this problem due to? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`quit` the driver after calling `find_element_by_class_name`.

According to selenium.webdriver [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver):

> quit()
>
> ```
> Closes the browser and shuts down the ChromeDriver executable that is started when starting the ChromeDriver
> ```

`driver.quit` closes the browser session and you can not use the driver after that to search for elements.